# C# how to add a json opening brace and closing brace to an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

How can I convert prop1 and prop2 from json to ExpandoObject syntax? They have an opening { and closing } and I cannot figure out how to represent this in the ExpandoObject syntax.

```
{
  "prop1": {
    "prop2": {
      "prop3": "value3",
      "prop4": "value4"
    }
}
```

}

```
// I need to convert the json to something like this
// but cannot figure out the syntax
// to get it to generate json correctly to look like the above


dynamic form = new ExpandoObject();


form.prop1 = "{"; // how do I add the {
form.prop2 = "{";  // how do I add the {
form.prop3 = "value3";
form.prop4 = "value4";
form.prop2 = "}"; // how to I add the close }
form.prop1 = "}"; // how do I add the closing }


// this string should look like the above json 
// but I cannot figure out the ExpandoObject syntax for the braces
string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form);
```

Comment: You need to post a brief question on how do you expect things to be.

Comment: Sorry about that I added a little more information. Thanks for taking a peek.

Comment: The JSON you posted is not correct. Why don't you use class objects to generate your JSONs? A description of what you're actually trying to accomplish could be better than asking to patch your own solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've fixed the json syntax. I have a custom json schema that needs to be built dynamically. Straight up converting class properties to json will not meet the json schema requirements. I'm using custom attributes to skip properties, add property names to a required json section in the schema, mark properties as optional so they are not included in the json schema,  and so forth. This is why I am rolling out my own, unfortunately. So in my C# class I have properties with custom attributes on them and these drive the creation of the json schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to understand how an ExpandoObject works before you can start adding braces or brackets.

[Documentation on ExpandoObject and how to add members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0)

Once you have gone through the documentation, you'll find the below example helpful. Basically, ExpandoObject is a representation of an object that contains dynamic properties. `{ }` represents an object, `[ ]` represents an array and so forth.

If you want to create the JSON object from your question, following is how you can accomplish it via ExpandoObject.

```
// Create the object prop2
dynamic prop2 = new ExpandoObject();
prop2.prop3 = "value3";
prop2.prop4 = "value4";
/*
    {
      "prop3": "value3",
      "prop4": "value4"
    }
*/

dynamic prop1 = new ExpandoObject();
prop1.prop2 = prop2;
/*
  {
    "prop2": {
      {
        "prop3": "value3",
        "prop4": "value4"
      }
    }
  }
*/

dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
root.prop1 = prop1;
/*
  {
    "prop1": {
      "prop2": {
        {
          "prop3": "value3",
          "prop4": "value4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
*/
```

In this example, what you are doing is,

1. Create an "object" that contains prop3 and prop4 as properties / keys that have values "value3" and "value4" respectively.
2. Assign the object from 1. to another object prop1 as "prop2"
3. Assign the entire object from 2 to a new object called root that will have object from 2 as value for "prop1" property.

Following is shorter way of doing it,

```
dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
root.prop1 = new ExpandoObject(); // means prop1 is an object.
root.prop1.prop2 = new ExpandoObject(); // means prop2 is an object
root.prop1.prop2.prop3 = "value3"; // assigns value3 to property prop3
root.prop1.prop2.prop4 = "value4"; // assigns value4 to property prop4
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I now understand that by doing prop1.prop2 = new ExpandoObject() creates the braces and I can then add child properties to prop2 and so forth. Thanks again for taking the time to respond!